# Passing inherited generic ability type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, casl

I'm trying to implement a universal wrapper for pages passed to `Route` that is limiting access to the page based on current user permissions. This component means to be universal because it's basically doing the same thing: if a user is allowed to go to this page - the page is shown, if not - the not found view is shown.

Implementation

```
const RouteCan = ({ action, subject }: RouteCan) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Can I={action} as={subject}>
        <Outlet />
      </Can>
      <Can not I={action} as={subject}>
        <NotFoundView />
      </Can>
    </>
  )

// Or ...

  if (can(action, subject)) return <Outlet />

  return <NotFoundView />
}
```

usage

```
<Route
  path="/secure-path"
  element={<RouteCan I="view" a="secure-info" />}
>
  /* inner routes */
</Route>
```

The thing is none of `<Can />` or `can` can accept as arguments just all possible pair variants as my application Ability type is defined as a union of only possible action-subject pairs:

```
type Ability =
  | ['manage' | 'view', 'secure-path']
  | ['manage' | 'view' | 'edit', 'public-path']

// This causing an error
type RouteCanProps = {
  I: Ability[0]
  as: Ability[1]
}
```

Is there any opportunity to create a type that provides only possible tuples of values, not just union of all possible actions and subjects separately?

[Link on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sara-zq87q9?file=/src/RouteCan.tsx) - Everything is working as expected, the problem is only on type of `RouteCan` props.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQEYEsA2LJwLyjnAHzgG0AiAWwEMA7SgcxlMLlIDcUYB3UgGhYGcYAYwCuAJxgBaKJTAALUgF08zMlVoMmRNh27NSMACaZeLKCKQYh02QsUBuUKEiw4AWUpRYh5OkwQAHgAVOBgADzAYakN+RFQMLGw4v0gAPhw4EPDI6NiglQB+OABvFXx8AEkALkziAAYHMvLKfhqg4gBGRpByuABfFRrqGFYYMUcQUAB6KbgXeAAlGH4RNDAM0pAZ3rhqlnV6Rn12LlIJ7d6WmtJBUQkbeTPp2b7mTYvyvYoaQ60WE702iMJnOs0urTMFisDwUoP6zmgi2Wq3WSQ8XiMvgSEHsQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame yes, the type is generating exact I need. I'm wondering why whether `RouteCan` component is calling with wrong params - the error is erasing but the editor suggests non-compatible tuple values anyway. Can we do something with it?

Comment: @wonderflame anyway your approach 90% solves my problem and answers the question so, please write an answer and I'll mark it as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which can be achieved with the following type:

```
type MappedAbility<T extends Ability = Ability> = T extends T
  ? {
      I: T[0];
      as: T[1];
    }
  : never;
```

The part that allows us to distribute is `T extends T`, after that the following code is executed for each member of the union separately.

Usage:

```
// type Result = {
//     I: "manage" | "view";
//     as: "secure-path";
// } | {
//     I: "manage" | "view" | "edit";
//     as: "public-path";
// }
type Result = MappedAbility;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQEYEsA2LJwLyjnAHzgG0AiAWwEMA7SgcxlMLlIDcUYB3UgGhYGcYAYwCuAJxgBaKJTAALUgF08zMlVoMmRNh27NSMACaZeLKCKQYh02QsUBuUKEiw4AWUpRYh5OkwQAHgAVOBgADzAYakN+RFQMLGw4v0gAPhw4EPDI6NiglQB+OABvFXx8AEkALkziAAYHMvLKfhqg4gBGRpByuABfFRrqGFYYMUcQUAB6KbgXeAAlGH4RNDAM0pAZ3rhqlnV6Rn12LlIJ7d6WmtJBUQkbeTPp2b7mTYvyvYoaQ60WE702iMJnOs0urTMFisDwUoP6zmgi2Wq3WSQ8XiMvgSEHsQA)

Comment: Can you explain how exactly `T extends T` works? Isn't this condition check always successful?

Comment: It is always successful. If you check the documentation that I've linked you will see: `When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type. For example, take the following. So when we do a conditional check on the union, the compiler distributes it. It can be `T extends any` as well, it can be anything that will definitely be always true. Check an example [here](https://tsplay.dev/wj8B6m)